# PHP duplicate name check entry

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a html form submitting data to my database. The user submits a name and a url with it and it gets stored into my table. What I am trying to achieve is when the user enters a name into the text field along with a url in the url field I want to search my database to see if there is a entry with that name already. If so I want it to not add the entry to the database.

This is what I currently have set up to submit the current data entered into the database.

```
$title=$_POST['title'];
$url=$_POST['url'];
$query = "INSERT INTO images VALUES ('$title','$url')";
mysql_query($query) or die('Error, insert query failed');
```

I am still fairly new to PHP so any help on how I can achieve this would be greatly appreciated! Thanks! :)

Comment: Before you start worrying about checking for dupes, worry about the gaping [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) hole in your code.

Comment: Are you aware of MYSQL SELECT and what it does? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you set title in database as `unique`, you can use:

```
INSERT INTO images SET 
    title = '$title', 
    url = '$url' 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    url = '$url'
```

This will insert a new row and if that particular title already exists in database update its url.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest, quickest way is to change your SQL to this (or something else which does the same job):

```
INSERT INTO images
     SELECT '$title',
            '$url'
       FROM DUAL
      WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (
              SELECT *
                FROM images
               WHERE title = '$title'
                 AND url = '$url'
            )
```

You can then use `mysql_num_rows`, `mysql_insert_id` or something similar to determine whether or not it's inserted a row.

Answer (score 0):

The quick/easy solution would be to do a select first and then if there are no records returned then do your insert.

**NOTE make sure you escape all inputs into your DB to reduce sql injection

Depending on the load you would expect the page to have you could go another route and create a stored procedure which will do that check if there is an item already there and then it will insert if it needs to.  Going the stored procedure route your your only making one call to your database.